# Problems indexing dictionary with date index

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am attempting to get a value from a nested dictionary where the index is date. The code to create my dictionary is:

```
PM25_dict = {}
for file in sorted(listdir('../Documents/Data')):
    print(file)
    if '.xls' in file:
        site_name = file.split('.xls')[0]
#         print(site_name)
        site_coordinate = (my_coordinates[my_coordinates.SITE == site_name].values[0,1],\
                            my_coordinates[my_coordinates.SITE == site_name].values[0,2])
        print(site_coordinate)
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(join('../Documents/Data', file))
            df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],dayfirst=True)
            df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']))
            df = df[df['PM']!= 'None']
            df_PM25 = df['PM'].to_frame().dropna()
            
            
            if len(df_PM25)>0:
                PM25_dict[site_name] = {'PM':df_PM25, 'coordinate':site_coordinate}
       
        except Exception as e:
            print('error:',e.args)
```

where `my_coordinates` is:

```
SITE        latitude    longitude
Station_A   26.845880   80.936554
Station_B   26.882100   80.930275
Station_C   26.868120   81.005119
Station_D   26.833997   80.891736
```

and the first two instances of my dictionary are:

```
dict={'Station_1': {'PM':                 PM
  DATE              
  2018-01-01  121.03
  2018-01-02  175.33
  2018-01-03  172.73
  2018-01-04  193.08
  2018-01-05  195.48
  ...            ...
  2021-12-27  132.58
  2021-12-28  140.92
  2021-12-29   101.1
  2021-12-30   70.38
  2021-12-31   65.14
  
  [1343 rows x 1 columns],
  'coordinate': (26.8821003, 80.9302753)},
 'Station_2': {'PM':                 PM
  DATE              
  2019-08-21   31.25
  2019-08-22   23.62
  2019-08-23   25.38
  2019-08-24   19.34
  2019-08-25   16.91
  ...            ...
  2021-12-27  109.66
  2021-12-28  118.33
  2021-12-29   76.68
  2021-12-30   74.75
  2021-12-31     166
  
  [852 rows x 1 columns],
  'coordinate': (26.86812, 81.005119)}}
```

The keys of each instance are 'PM', and 'coordinate'. Here is what I have so far when it comes to trying to get the 'PM' value based on the given 'date_index':

```
date_index = '2018-01-01'

dict['Station_1']['PM'].index == date_index
```

Which returns an array of

```
array([ True, False, False, ..., False, False, False])
```

I get the 'True', since i am seeking '2018-01-01'. But how do I get the actual 'PM' value of 121.03? I've always struggled understanding dictionaries in Python, so any insight or help is much appreciated. Apologies if the dictionary terminology is incorrect.

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for a normal dictionary, what library are you using? Looks a bit like it could be numpy but it's not obvious.

Comment: Yes, it is numpy. I have edited my question to include the code used to create the dictionary!

Comment: `dict['Station_1']['PM'].at[date_index]`?

Answer (score 0):

Side note: You shouldn't name your variable `dict` because `dict` is a builtin type in python and creating a variable with that name shadows the type. Call the variable something else (like `dct`, for example).

You're not indexing a dictionary. The date index is part of a *pandas dataframe*. You see the line that you do `df = pd.read_excel(join('../Documents/Data', file))`? That makes `df` a dataframe.

When you do `dct['Station_1']['PM']`, you get *this dataframe!*. How can you get the item in the `"PM"` column of this dataframe that has the index given by `date_index`? Use `.loc`

```
dct['Station_1']['PM'].loc[date_index, "PM"]
```

Comment: This gave me the PM i was wanting. Thank you for breaking it down for me. This is someone elses code so I only half understand what they did.