# Indexing dataframes with date index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I previously asked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859494/problems-indexing-dictionary-with-date-index) how to properly get the item in the "PM" column of the produced dataframe that has the index given by date_index. This solution provided in the answers worked:

```
date_index = '2021-12-31'
dct['Station_1']['PM'].loc[date_index, "PM"]
```

and would give me the PM value that was listed in the example dataframes provided in that question.

However, now when i run the above code, I get output like this:

```
DATE
2021-12-31    50
Name: PM, dtype: int64
```

I'm not sure what this information is. The structure of my spreadsheets that I run through is the same, two columns each with `DATE` and `PM`. All I still want is that lone 50, output alone. Can someone help me with that, and maybe help me figure out why the output of code that worked now outputs something else?

Answer (score 1):

Add `.squeeze()` to "squeeze out" the lone value:

```
>>> dct['Station_1']['PM'].loc[date_index, "PM"].squeeze
50
```